# Having JToggleButton with no border?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtogglebutton

I'm trying to have `JToggleButton` buttons that don't have a border normally, and just show the icons I provide. But then when they are clicked, I want the selected button to show.

I know that by using `setLayout(null)`. The initial state works, but then when I click it, the border doesn't show up. There must be some simple border call I'm missing. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nrW2.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nrW2.png#1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question but maybe the following will help:

```
button.setBorderPainted(false);
```

Comment: That does the same as setting the border to null. See the pics I added for a better visual.

Comment: Actually I figued out a way where I have an if state that, if(selected)-BorderPainted(true) else BorderPainted(false). So I guess that works out. Thanks